# to "would" a noun? (British English)

Tags: word-usage, sentence-meaning

Reading [**this article,**](https://www.yahoo.com/news/prime-minister-jeremy-corbyn-markets-122017281.html) the second paragraph says,

> **The pound’s instant reaction was to strengthen versus the dollar, a somewhat surprising response *to would* will be a fevered six weeks of opinion polls and uncertainty (assuming there are no last-minute changes of heart from Labour lawmakers).** The fracturing of British politics along Brexiter and non-Brexiter lines makes elections fiendishly difficult to predict and voter polling hard to trust. But it’s the overriding expectation of currency traders that Prime Minister Boris Johnson’s championing of Brexit will win him a majority.

I think the bold-Italic word is defined by the Merriam Unabridged,

> would (noun)
>    plural -s
>   :  a conditional or undecided wish or intention

The first question is, is this my understanding correct?.

The second question is, what could the bold sentence mean? The GBP is "reading" the result of the 6 weeks polls and uncertainty in the future?? (Here the auxiliary "will" is making me confused.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a typo/proofreading error (or ***two*** errors, depending on how you look at it). There's a missing ***what*** before ***would***, and an unwanted ***will*** after it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Please do as you say. How can **I**, assume before asking this question, this could be a **typo**? Had you been a learner of my country's language, which is **completely** different from yours, would you yourself expect something is wrong so this would be a typo when you are reading **our** newspapers or articles? You are almost assuming I am a native speaker, the reality is completely opposite. Probably my vocabulary is around 4,000 - 5,000 at most, which is lower than 4th graders in your country. **Thank you**

Comment: @KentaroTomono - Having your question closed doesn't mean that you did anything wrong, just that the question will probably not be useful for future visitors to the site.

Comment: What @Reinstate Monica (great handle, kudos! :) said. I intend no criticism of you for asking (how indeed *could* you know?). My reason for closevoting is just that this particular combination of Question+Answer ***has no relevance for future visitors***. But at least you have ***got*** your answer! (Although to be honest I'd have thought the text of my closevote would have dealt with that - no need for anyone to actually post or upvote a "formal" answer.)

Comment: @FumbleFingers  What of the second part of the OP's question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the beginning part of the article, I believe there is an error in the sentence you quote.

The phrase immediately preceding the puzzling word "**would**" is "a surprising response to". This phrase should by all means be followed by some kind of 
noun/pronoun element. "Would", or even "would will", cannot act as a noun, and just can't be correct here.

I think the author meant to say "a surprising response to ... *what* will be ..." or possibly, "a surprising response to ... *what* would be"... Perhaps he was even dithering between "what would" and "what will", and "would will" accidentally made it onto the page....?

In any case I think it's just a mistake.

Comment: Yeah, my first thought was the same.  They probably meant to type *what*.

Comment: Sometimes writing has typos, and just plain goofs. It's easy to spot them in your own language, but when you are learning another language, it's pretty natural to assume that anytime you are confused, the problem must be yours.

Comment: Please calm down, @Kentaro. If you think about it, you should be able to see why there's nothing you can learn about English from the "typo" element of your question. All that can tell you is *Writers and proofreaders sometimes make meaningless mistakes,* which should be obvious anyway. But there ***is*** something you could usefully learn here about *Why should it be **would** rather than **will**?*

Answer (score 1):

With regard to the meaning of the bold part, I can see why you would find it a little confusing. "The pound" in this case is not a physical item, but rather a metaphor for 'currency trading' which is of course (mostly) carried out by real people, with real feelings, and it is those people who are 'reading' the polls.

Comment: Thank you for the reading. +1. Though, however, I happened to have found out a paid writer can make such a (as Lorel answered) mistake. To non native speakers, we have no option but to believe what native speakers wrote is correct firstly.

Comment: To be fair, it is more likely to be the fault of an editor - pieces like these often need to be stretched (or more often squeezed) a little to fit, which makes it very easy to break an idiom. Still a professional though!

Comment: It is helpful to account for the context, too. Mistakes like this one are not all that uncommon in newspapers or daily news columns, where journalists are often asked to value speed over accuracy. On the other hand, if the quote came from, say, the ninth edition of a textbook, or a longer piece from a monthly periodical, we'd expect that to be examined much more carefully before going to print.